# what language are the apps for the iphone created with?

Tags: iphone

what language is it similar to? cause i was looking at the dev page on apple for the iphone and it doesnt look like anything that i'm used to or know.

Comment: It's Objective-C, Satan's own version of C straight from the seventh circle of Hell, close enough to C and C++ to lull you into a false sense of security, but different enough to smack you over the back of the head and steal your wallet when you're not looking :-)

Comment: @Pax: If that was an answer I would have voted it up :)

Comment: @Pax Tell us how you really feel about Objective-C ;-)

Comment: If that was an answer I would had downvoted it.

Answer (score 10):

iPhone applications are created using objective-C as the primary language. You can also use C/C++ in the applications, but the Cocoa Touch API uses objective-C.

Also, if you have never programmed on the Mac before it will take some getting used to. Apple uses the MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern extensively in their programming model.

Here is a good site with several iPhone apps with source code:
http://appsamuck.com/

If you need a crash course in objective-C check out this link:
http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Comment: not that this is the 'original MVC': the modular, somewhat OO, design for GUI apps.  no relation to the (currently more popular) 'web MVC': the layered architecture for web apps.

Answer (score 7):

It's [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C).

Here's [Apple's Programming Guide Introduction](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html)

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the answer is [Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html). For current production-ready languages, that's it. In the not-yet production ready category, it looks like the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Iphone) folks are able to cross-compile C# to native code for deployment on the iPhone using the Apple toolchain. Much of the CocoaTouch API is not yet exposed to Mono, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

[Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html)